# Django How to access another object by having a user name?

Tags: django

I have this in models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    selectat = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Score(models.Model):
    VALUE = (
        (1, "Nota 1"),
        (2, "Nota 2"),
        (3, "Nota 3"),
        (4, "Nota 4"),
        (5, "Nota 5"),
        (6, "Nota 6"),
        (7, "Nota 7"),
        (8, "Nota 8"),
        (9, "Nota 9"),
        (10, "Nota 10"),
    )
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0, related_name='user_to')
    nota = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=VALUE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_to)
```

How can i access the score objects by having the user?

When i give the user to score object i can get the notes.

```
x = Score.objects.filter(user_to__username='Fane')
x
<QuerySet [<Punctaj: Fane>, <Punctaj: Fane>]>
for a in x:
    print(a.nota)

1
5
```

I want to use something like this:

```
y = CustomUser.objects.get(id=7)
x = x.score.all()
for a in x:
    print(a.nota)

1
5
```

But this won't work, it's giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'score'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two foreign keys from CustomUser to Score. The first one, `user_from`, does not set a related_name, so it uses the default, which is `score_set`:

```
x = y.score_set.all()
```

The second does set a related_name, so you use that:

```
x = y.user_to.all()
```

Note that this does not make much sense as a related name, since it points to scores, not users; it should probably be something like `scores_to_user`.

Comment: the second works :) what did you mean about "Note that this does not make much sense as a related name, since it points to scores, not users; it should probably be something like scores_to_user"

Comment: I'm not sure what you didn't understand. My comment was that the name doesn't describe what it points to.

Comment: aaa, because they are made in my language and i've changed everything so you can understand :) i forgot to change those too